# java, processing Nested Loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I use this code:

```
int contadorA = 1, contadorB = 1;

while (contadorA <= 5) {
    println ("banking " + contadorA);
    contadorA++;

    while (contadorB <= 3) {
         println ("month " + contadorB);
        contadorB++;
    }
}
```

the code print this:

banking 1
month 1
month 2
month 3
banking 2
banking 3
banking 4
banking 5

AND I NEED THAT PRINT THIS:

banking 1
month 1
month 2
month 3
banking 2
month 1
month 2
month 3
banking 3
month 1
month 2
month 3
banking 4
month 1
month 2
month 3
banking 5
month 1
month 2
month 3

Comment: Check the scope of your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't resetting the second counter inside the loop.  You need to do this:

```
int contadorA = 1, contadorB = 1;

while (contadorA <= 5) {

    println ("banking " + contadorA);
    contadorA++;

    contadorB = 1;
    while (contadorB <= 3) {

    println ("month " + contadorB);
    contadorB++;


    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! that is, yeah, I need reset the counter of the 2nd loop (Im new to programming)

Comment: I see no point in this spoon feeding here.
@Vineet Reynolds had given the correct hint which the op should've followed up on. That way he'd have understood his error better.

Comment: I do actually agree.  The only reason I posted code is because I overlooked the homework tag. @Vineet Reynolds did post correct information that would have lead the op to the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I won't post code, my apologies.

I'll give a hint. In the inner loop, you are not resetting the counter, on entering it. This means that `contadorB`'s value after the execution of the first outer loop is 4, and it will never enter the inner loop again.

Here's another hint. Step through the code in the debugger (and watch the value of `contadorB)` if you haven't understood my earlier hint.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `int contadorB = 1;` in the first while loop but before second while loop. In other words, you are just resetting the variable for every iteration of the first while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of contadorB at the end of the second `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code will point out your issue:

```
int contadorA = 1, contadorB = 1;

while (contadorA <= 5) {
    println ("banking " + contadorA);
    contadorA++;

    while (contadorB <= 3) {
         println ("month " + contadorB);
        contadorB++;
    }
    println ("contadorA: " + contadorA + "\n contadorB: " + contadorB + "\n");
}
```